# Logistic equation with or without brackets is correct?

Tags: math, equation, logarithm, logistics

I am coding a logistic function where the function reads:
Now to calculate the % chance of an event happening I have been using:

```
 e^x/1+e^x
```

now my answer changes significantly depending on if I use:

`e^x/1+e^x` or `e^x/(1+(e^x))`

which of these two is correct ?

thanks
Hyflex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precedence question.  The correct, unambiguous answer is,

```
(e^x)/(1+(e^x))
```